# Uncompleted installation files using apt-get

Tags: linux, apt-get, linux-mint

Often I install softwares/packages using `apt-get`.
If the installation is stopped or interrupted anyhow, 
then how to find and remove the partially installed files? Besides if I install the same package later, will the apt-get installation process create duplicate files?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And then:

update, upgrade, reinstall, etc...